# No weight $2$ newforms on $\Gamma_0(4)$?

Tags: modular-forms, theta-functions

How could it be there are no modular forms of weight $2$ and level $4$. In the lmfdb database?  We can easily think of one:  $\theta(z)^4$ with 
 $\theta(z)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2}$ . Where are we supposed to look?

http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/4/2/1/?group=0

[image]

Comment: @reuns really?!

Comment: It is **not a cusp form** since the coef of $q^0$ is $1$. It is something like $2G_2(z)- G_2(4z)$. By the [four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) its coefficients are multiplicatives and since it is not a cusp form, it is automatically an Eisenstein series.

Comment: `M := ModularForms(Gamma0(4),2); Basis(M); EisensteinSeries(M);`  http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/